# How to export .obj file with rig(bones) in blender

Tags: object, blender

I am unable to export rigs with .obj file in blender.I know that object can be exported with rigs by .fbx and other formats but the format I require is .obj. Please tell me if there is a way to export .obj file with rigs armature in blender.

Answer (score 4):

In all versions of blender this is not possible with obj files. They are mesh and texture files only.  OBJ is a very old format.  Try using DAE files.  They are beautiful magic.  If all else fails use fbx.